# SweetAlert alert shows partially on view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, sweetalert

I am creating a personal project on ASP.NET MVC5 using SweetAlert for handling message alerts.
The thing is, on an HTML5 button, on the event "onClick" I'm testing a simple alert message, but, the message only shows for a couple of milliseconds, I can't even press the "OK" button, the Console window in the chrome browser is not showing any kind of error message.

I have added the sweetalert.css on my Content folder and the sweetalert.js script on my Scripts folder making references to the BundleConfig.cs like these:

[image: BundleConfig]

On the _Layout.cshtml I have added the files like this:

.css stylesheet:

[image: .css stylesheet]

.js script:

[image: .js script]

Finally, in the view, inside a div, I have added a button with the "onClick" event calling "test()"

[image: view]

[image: tag script]

Once I press the button as I said before, I can barely see the alert but it only shows instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this button inside a form?

If so I would imagine this is because the page is refreshing. Buttons inside forms will submit the form unless explicitly stated as type="button"

So what's happening is that the sweet alert is functioning properly, but the form is being submitted straight after causing the page to refresh and naturally, the sweet alert to disappear.

```
<button type="button" onclick="test()" class="btn btn-danger">....</button>
```

Comment: The button is inside a form, and I didnt't know this was the issue. After I placed the button outside, it worked perfectly. Thank you Jacob.